# Authenticate Firebase in Polymer using OAuth token

Tags: oauth, firebase, polymer, firebase-authentication, firebase-polymer

I have a Firebase database that authenticates with a Google account. Currently I have a `<google-signin-aware>` element that details the app's sign-in details for use with the Google Sign-in API, and upon sign-in authenticates a Firebase reference with the access token returned by the Google sign-in.

From the callback for `<google-signin-aware>` element on successful sign-in:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<myapp>.firebaseio.com");
var access_token = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token;
ref.authWithOAuthToken("google", access_token, function (error, authData){/*...*/});
```

To try to integrate further with Polymer, I'm migrating to the `<firebase-auth>` element which is a "wrapper for the Firebase authentication API". However I cannot find an equivalent method to  authenticate with an access token. The `login()` method has two parameters, is there any way to feed the access token to the login method so that Firebase authenticates with this token rather than its own pop-up window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<firebase-auth>` element has an internal Firebase reference `ref` that you can access by calling

```
var ref = document.querySelector('#fbauth').ref
```

And then auth as normal

```
var access_token = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token;
ref.authWithOAuthToken("google", access_token, function (error, authData){/*...*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested by my custom set that extends Firebase Polymer element set: https://github.com/MeTaNoV/firebase-element-extended