# Firebase Auth and Google Calendar using Polymer

Tags: firebase, polymer-1.0

Referencing [Firebase Auth and Google Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932427/firebase-auth-and-google-calendar), how do I do this with Polymer elements?

On my page, I added a google-signin element

```
<google-signin
   client-id="xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</google-signin>
```

I then waited for the `google-signin-success` event to be fired and got the access token with

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().hg.access_token)
```

How do I login with firebase-auth? I tried adding the firebase-auth element like so in my page

```
<firebase-auth id="authenticate"
               user="{{user}}"
               location="{{location}}"
               ref="{{refauth}}"
               provider="google">
</firebase-auth>
```

and called it programmatically like so

```
  signIn: function() {
    var params = {token: "ya29.xxxxx"};
    this.$.authenticate.login(params);
  },

  signOut: function() {
    this.$.authenticate.logout();
    this.user = null;
  }
});
```

however, firebase-auth would still pop up a google signin dialog. How do I login with the access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution here [Authenticate Firebase in Polymer using OAuth token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801186/authenticate-firebase-in-polymer-using-oauth-token) although I expected firebase-auth login() method to work. As a workaround or till a better answer comes along, I'd recommend the solution above.

**Update**:
Rev 1.0.12 of firebase-element now supports headless login using OAuth token.

Comment: you can also take a look here: https://github.com/MeTaNoV/firebase-element-extended

Comment: Most likely, firebase-element doesn't support [authenticating with a third party oauth token](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithoauthtoken.html), but simply calls authWithOAuthPopup(). Sounds like a feature request.

Comment: @PascalGula I took a quick look at  github.com/MeTaNoV/firebase-element-extended but do not see how I can login with an OAuth token.